# Determination of pass/fail for unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing

Would it be fair to say that almost all unit test frameworks use assertions, or a single assertion, to determine whether or not a test has passed or failed?

In particular, are there any frameworks which instead compare textual output from a test against a known-good 'golden' version to determine whether the test has passed or failed?

The code I'm trying to test is stateful, and the methods can have a long history. My thinking is that I should be generating textual output recording this history (maybe a couple of dozen state transitions), and comparing this to the expected transitions, so I get a single pass/fail for the entire history.

I could instead break a single test into 20 tests, and set up a new state individually for every test, and then assert that the next state is as expected for all 20 tests, but this seems to be pointless and wasteful.

*edit*

To clarify - I'm not looking for a tool, or a recommendation. I'm already doing what I suggested, 'manually', and I was hoping to get some insight as to whether this counted as 'unit testing'. I didn't want to actually ask that question as I thought it would result in lots of downvotes and no answers. OTOH, if any 'real' frameworks do this as well, then that actually answers the question.

Comment: "are there any frameworks" I'm not sure this question is not offtopic on this site, but probably you should specify your platform

Comment: Again, the *"lets close everything which literally violates the rules, so we don't have to switch on our brains and think if the question can be interpreted in an on-topic way"* party around here? Come on, guys, don't read this as a tool request question, read it as a question on how to achieve this kind of tests using a standard unit testing framework.

Comment: Look into snapshot testing. The concept is simple, you run your tests using the SUT. The test then generates a snapshot of the value found, and every run after that will compare the value returned to the snapshot already generated. This is practical for enforcing JSON/XML/HTML output for example.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a specific unit testing framework for this. We implemented such kind of automated tests using file comparisons against an "expected file" in several different variants utilizing NUnit (but it works with any other unit testing framework as well).

Though such a functionality could theoretically be provided by the framework, to my experience, in most real-world cases it is pretty easy to implement a text comparer, even if you have to tailor the comparer and the infrastructure around it to your specific requirements. So I doubt if the framework would provide you with a ready-made reusable solution, you could really save a lot of code with it.

Some things to consider:

- When a comparison of the actual text against the expected one fails, make sure you get a sensible error message telling the tester precisely where the failure happened. For some scenarios, it may be sufficient to log just the first line number which differs, for other scenarios, you may require to log all different lines and which differences occur. And if your text file is an XML or JSON file, you probably need to show the differences or their location in a different manner.
- Make sure your tests don't become brittle this way - the text comparer may have to be tolerant against certain kind of changes in the output, depending on the case.
- Make sure the test sets can be easily extended and updated. It is a good idea to have a folder "expected_output" (under version control) and a folder "actual_output" (not under version control), and when it turns you need to update the expected output, just copy the specific files from the "actual" folder to the "expected" folder.

Be aware that these kinds of tests are not the ones which help you if you want to do TDD, they are no replacement for "real" unit tests. Nethertheless they can be a sensible support for a "test after" strategy, to find regressions when code is extended or refactored, but the behaviour for previous input data should not change.

Answer (score 2):

There is a category of tests called approvals that compare actuals to a manually approved last known good state. https://github.com/approvals Also snapshot testing has a similar concept as mentioned in the comments. I have seen approval tests implemented in a variety of test frameworks.